# DataFrame.loc to determine Values creates SyntaxError

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'd like to determine if the output number in the new column "Calculator" should be a 5 or a 6 depending on the [State] and [Original_Creditor].  When I look for values in one column of the df I can get a result, but when I search for two pieces of data, I receive a syntax error.

The code is:

```py
df.loc(df[df['State'] == 'ID' & (df[df['Orignal_Creditor'].str.contains('Visa', case=False) == True, 'Calculator'] = '5'
df.loc(df[df['State'] == 'OR|WA' & (df[df['Orignal_Creditor'].str.contains('Visa', case=False) == True, 'Calculator'] = '6'
```

The error message states:

```
Input In [13] df = df.loc(df[df['State'] == 'ID' & (df[df['Orignal_Creditor'].str.contains('Visa', case=False) == True, 'Calculator'] = '5'
                                                                                                                                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: FOr one thing, `.loc[]` uses square brackets, not parentheses. For another, check your open and close brackets and parentheses, you seem to be missing at least one closing bracket and 2 closing parentheses

Comment: correctly formatted error message should use `^` to show you in which place in line can be the problem. But is seems you have wrong brackets.

Answer (score 0):

It looks you have wrong brackets and too many `df[`

```
df.loc[ (df['State'] == 'ID') & df['Orignal_Creditor'].str.contains('Visa', case=False), 'Calculator'] = '5'
df.loc[ (df['State'] == 'OR|WA') & df['Orignal_Creditor'].str.contains('Visa', case=False), 'Calculator'] = '6'
```

or more readable

```
df.loc[ 
  (df['State'] == 'ID') & df['Orignal_Creditor'].str.contains('Visa', case=False), 
  'Calculator'
] = '5'

df.loc[ 
  (df['State'] == 'OR|WA') & df['Orignal_Creditor'].str.contains('Visa', case=False), 
  'Calculator'
] = '6'
```